# How to use slf4j + log4j in hibernate (Java Project) without using maven

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I want to adding log use slf4j + log4j into my java project without using maven,
i was put the library (slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar + log4j-1.2.14.jar) into my classpath but my log not create and i got this error

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

this is my log4j.properties,

```
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\coreservice.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5 %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log message to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

# Log everything. Good for troubleshooting
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO

# Log all JDBC parameters
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=ALL
```

note: I am using eclipse juno for this project,

any help will be pleasure,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder says:

> This error is reported when the org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
>   class could not be loaded into memory. This happens when no
>   appropriate SLF4J binding could be found on the class path. Placing
>   one (and only one) of slf4j-nop.jar, slf4j-simple.jar,
>   slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or logback-classic.jar on the class
>   path should solve the problem. SINCE 1.6.0 As of SLF4J version 1.6, in
>   the absence of a binding, SLF4J will default to a no-operation (NOP)
>   logger implementation.

I think you're missing the slf4j-log4j-xxx.jar in your classpath:
[Config SLF4J using library to use LOG4J configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303157/config-slf4j-using-library-to-use-log4j-configuration)

If you just need logging with slf4j then I would prefer logback (http://logback.qos.ch/) as it's a native implementation for the SLF4J API. Others are "Wrapped implementations" according to the slf4j website.

Comment: still not work for me :(,i have add slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar, slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar and log4j-1.2.16.jar into my classpath and my log still not create... there are something that i missed??

Comment: that's error was gone when i add slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar and slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar.... but my log still not create, any idea??

Comment: hi @aumand that's error was gone and the program can create the log file now... but can i insert some directory to save where my log file is it?? because it just can create log file in the projet folder ~

Comment: I think you can specify the filename within the properties (like you already did in your initial post):
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\coreservice.log

Comment: yap, i can save my log file into different directory now.... this code not work `C:\\coreservice.log` and then i change to `C:\\Log\\coreservice.log` and everything ok, thank you @aumand :)

Comment: no problem. If your problem is solved, then please mark the answer as accepted.. Thank you!